# SharePoint 2013 doesn't send emails

Tags: powershell, email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My SharePoint 2013 has stopped sending emails suddenly. I have checked my SMTP settings and outgoing email from central admin and have tried to use PowerShell to test it via this command:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($spWeb ,0,0,$email,$subject,$body)
```

Which returns `false`.

Can you please advise what else I could check?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, this question might do better on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

If your settings in Central Admin is OK (there is 2 level settings, Farm level and WebApplication Level), maybe your SMTP  server is down. 
If your smtp server is OK, you can check the SharePoint Log (using ULSviewer for exemple) to see what's wrong, don't forget to increasing the level of verbosity.

hope you will found your problem